# Magento 2 Migration Settings error

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.2, layout, migration

I migrate settings from Magento 1.9.3.10 to Magento 2.3, after the migration was successful when I try to reindex or flush de cache from command line I have this error:

```
  The website with id 0 that was requested wasn't found. Verify the website a
  nd try again.
```

Also in the exception.log file I see this error:

```
main.CRITICAL: The website with id 0 that was requested wasn't found. Verify the website and try again. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): The website with id 0 that was requested wasn't found. Verify the website and try again. at /var/www/clients/client0/web15/web/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/WebsiteRepository.php:110)"} []
```

What I can do to fix this? or what can be the problem?

Thank you

[image]

Core_config_data with the scope=websites

[image]

Comment: So have you tried migration in empty Magento 2 instance? From error I can guess something in core_config data is pointing to a website with id 0 whereas the website id doesn't exist. Can you please share your store_website table

Comment: @RajMohanR indeed I migrate the settings in a empty Magento 2.3.2 instance. I edit my post and I add the store_website table, can you check please?

Comment: There is no website with website id 0. Can you please check in core_config data if there some config for website id 0\

Comment: @RajMohanR how I can check this?

Comment: @RajMohanR can you check please, I edit my post, this fields are with the scope=websites in the core_config_data

Comment: @RajMohanR indeed you have right I change the scope_id for a few fields and everything seems to be fine now

Comment: @Robert how can u resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check the website ID. Some of the configurations are there for the website with ID 0 which we can conclude from the error message. So check your `store_website` table. If there is no website with `website_id` 0, please check your `core_config_data` table for configurations with `scope_id` 0. You can manually change those to solve this issue at the go. Moreover please check for those configurations in Magento 1 with `scope_id` 0. It will give an idea about the `scope_id` mismatch.